# SQL find duplicates of LIKE records

Tags: sql, db2

I need to find duplicate of "like" records. This is what I mean by that.

I have catalog numbers as characters, like 'abc123' or 'a1b2c3'
production all the sudden started padding these to 10 places, so new ids go in as 0000abc123
so they are off to the races putting data in and it's "technically" unique.

What I need to do is hunt down all the records that have matches between the not-padded and the padded.

I have tried this

```
SELECT p.sku, COUNT(p.id)
FROM  products p
GROUP BY p.sku
HAVING COUNT(p.id) > 1
```

Which gives me a count of duplicates (helpful, but not helpful enough)

I think I need a UNION  but I am unclear how to proceed.
ANY help is appreciated

So to state it in English

Find all records with a length of 10 and find any other records where the right most characters match the right most characters of the length of 10 records.

so

```
00000asdfg would match 'asdfg' but would not match 'sdfg'
```

I guess I'm trying to match on any characters NOT '0' on the left

DB2 v10

Comment: What's the database. The solution is very database-specific.

Comment: Database is IBM DB2 v10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self join:

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.sku, p2.sku matching_sku
FROM products p1 LEFT JOIN products p2
ON p2.sku = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM p1.sku)  
WHERE LENGTH(p1.sku) = 10
```

This query will return all the rows conatining `sku`s with length = 10 and any matching `sku`s by removing the leading `0`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the `id`s first, and then it's easy to find duplicates. For example:

```
select
  pid
from (
  select
    sku,
    id,
    lpad(id, 10, '0') as pid
  from products
) x
group by pid
having count(pid) > 1
```

See running example at [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=bc444f67b134c968db5156976856493e).

You don't mention the architecture of your DB2 database (iSeries, LUW, z/OS). If `LPAD()` is not available in your architecture, you can use a combination of `REPEAT()` and `RIGHT()` to get the same result. For example:

```
select
  pid
from (
  select
    sku,
    right(repeat('0', 10) || id, 10) as pid
  from products
) x
groub by pid
where count(pid) > 1
```

Comment: trying your first suggestion....
SQL Error [42903]: Invalid use of an aggregate function or OLAP function.. SQLCODE=-120, SQLSTATE=42903, DRIVER=4.15.134
  com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: Invalid use of an aggregate function or OLAP function.. SQLCODE=-120, SQLSTATE=42903, DRIVER=4.15.134 (I believe it's an iSeries )

Comment: @j-p Fixed syntax issue and added a running example. Check it.